# IIS web config error

Tags: windows, web-config, iis-7.5

I have recently been trying to install TargetProcess on my windows 7 machine.

I have gotten so far as to successfully install it while running IIS and an SQLEXPRESS instance. when I point my web browser at the index page there is an error in the config file.

```
Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'Reroute-x32-2.0'
```

Can anyone advise on how best to proceed?

thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an error (duplicate entry) in the site's web.config file. Have a look through the web.config or machine.config, look for something like

```
<add name="Reroute-x32-2.0" ...
```

Don't forget that config files are hierarchical, so you might have this entry in one config, and inadvertantly added it to another config file higher up in the IIS folder hierarchy (or machine.config).

Comment: So, when I find this line should I simply remove it? Apologies but I am new to IIS, this attempt to install TargetProcess is my first time trying to configure it.

Comment: Yes, assuming you find the above line in two (or more .config) files on your machine, you should be able to remove one of them. Which one you remove depends on whether you want this "TargetProcess" to apply to the whole of IIS or just a particular website.

Comment: Note that config files work in a hierarchical way, so machine-level settings in machine.config can be overridden, removed, or appended to by an individual website's web.config file. It's also possible to have web.config files elsewhere in the IIS folder hierarchy, e.g. a config file in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ will affect all sites beneath that folder. So make sure you search thoroughly for config files on your machine, in order to find these duplicate lines.